# How to access BootGrid cell by column index or column name?

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

In selected data and other properties events and methods I get a rows[] object.

1. How do I access a certain cell in that row. Can I use the column index?
   *e.g. for column 2 (starting with zero) can I write: `var text = rows[5][2]`?*
2. Can I somehow get the cell by the row number and column id?
3. Can I somehow get the column index from its id?

I can get the columnid from the getColumnHeaders()... but:

4. Can I somehow get the column NAME (as set in the html) from its id or index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an `Array` of rows, you can access a specific row by its index and a cell by its column identifier.

Access a single row:

```
var row = rows[0];
```

Access a specific cell of the first row:

```
var cell = rows[0]["column-id"];
```

If you need access to the columns, you can request the `Array` of columns via the method `getColumnSettings`. See example below:

```
var columns = $("#grid").bootgrid("getColumnSettings");
```

By the way, the column `Array` has the same order as the columns of your *HTML* table columns, because they are linked to them.

Here is the complete example:

```
var columns = $("#grid").bootgrid("getColumnSettings");
var firstColumn = columns[0];
var cell = rows[0][firstColumn.id];
```

Comment: how do I get the html name that I gave the column?